# How to set Specific Asymetric Constraint in Orbeon Form

Tags: validation, orbeon, check-constraints

I am trying to build an Orbeon form where I want to capture Number (along with hyphen or Space) in specific format. For example:

Field1 -> 11 1111 1111111 11 or 11-1111-1111111-11

I tried adding Constraint formula `matches(., "^\s*\d{15}\s*$")` which restrict the user to not to add more than 15 numbers. However, I cannot achieve the format I am looking for.

[image: Image for your reference]

Comment: To those who have spend time to read through the question, I was able to manage to write the contstraint:
**matches(.,"^\s*\d{2}[-]\d{4}[-]\d{7}[-]\d{3}\s*$")**

If anyone come up with a better solution, please feel free to add comment to it.
Cheers,
Aman

Answer (score 0):

Very much inline with your comment, the following works for me:

```
^\s*\d{2}[- ]\d{4}[- ]\d{7}[- ]\d{2}\s*$
```

- Note the `[- ]` instead of just the `[-]` that you had in your comment above. (I suspect you had the space in your actual regex, but it got lost, maybe by Stack Overflow as the regex wasn't marked as "code" in your comment.)
- Your example only had 2 digits in the last group, so above I used a `\d{2}`.